# JMeter - Using the result of OracleSQL procedure in another request

Tags: jmeter

I have a Thread Group that looks something like this:

```
JDBC Connection
Request_1
Request_2
```

Request_1 is an OracleSQL procedure that returns a number.

```
declare
result NUMERIC;
begin
    result:=procedure1();
end;
```

Request_2 needs the number returned by Request_1.

```
begin
    procedure(?);
end;
result
NUMERIC
```

How do I pass the result of Request_1 to Request_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you need to add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) post-processor to your Request 1.

If result value is a number, i.e. "10" you can do the following to extract it.

- Add "Regular Expression Extractor" Post Processor to request 1
- Fill "Regular Expression Extractor" fields as follows:

  - Reference Name: RESULT
  - Regular Expression: (\d+)
  - Template: $1$

You can refer RESULT variable in your Request2 as ${RESULT}

```
begin
procedure(${RESULT});
end;
result
NUMERIC
```

You can test your regular expression using [Jakarta ORO Demonstration applet](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/demo.html)

Comment: Using regular expressions is unnecessary. I've already resolved my problem and will post the solution soon.